# storekit support in ios5 simulator - keyboard doesn't work?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, simulator, storekit

Wow, finally the XCode 4.2 / iOS5 simulator has StoreKit support.

In my app I've noticed that when StoreKit asks for an AppleID/password, I can enter that information using the simulator on-screen keyboard, but NOT via the Mac keyboard.

Is this normal or do I have some other issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the same issue but I do this as a workaround:

Type your password somewhere, copy it, paste into the simulator using cmd + v and then use the iOS paste function (press and hold in the passeword field) to paste it into the dialogue.

Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Thanks oskob.  I really just wanted confirmation that this wasn't just me.  Does your app present a purchase UI from a modal view controller?  I'm wondering if this could be the issue.  Or, do you show a progress-spinner during the purchase process?  I use MBProgressHUD and perhaps it is interfering?

Comment: I do not use a modal controller, just an ordinary ViewController. I have an activity indicator spinning but that's it. Maybe this is a security thing so you can't simulate external keyboards to enter app store credentials for making purchase without the user knowing or something.

Answer (score 3):

From the iOS Simulator menu, select "Reset Content and Settings..."

Sometimes the simulator just gets confused and loses the ability to interact with the keyboard.  This should fix it.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't fix it.  All other textfields in my app accept input via the Mac keyboard while running in the simulator.

Comment: this worked for me, TomSwift must have had another kind of issue